# How to get an Authenticated User's Details in Spring Security OAuth2

Tags: spring, spring-boot, spring-security, spring-data-rest, spring-security-oauth2

I am unable to extract the current logged in user in Spring Security OAuth2. My goal is to extract the user when the create event on ClientSuggestion entity is triggered and persist it to the database.

Employee.java

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "er_employee")
public class Employee implements Serializable {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    @Column(name = "id")
    private Long id;

    @Column(name = "username", unique = true)
    @NotNull
    @Size(max = 10)
    private String username;

    @Column(name = "password_hash")
    @NotNull
    @Size(min = 8, max = 512)
    private String password;


    @Column(name = "email_verification_token")
    @Size(max = 512)
    private String emailVerificationToken;

    @Column(name = "password_reset_token")
    @Size(max = 512)
    private String passwordResetToken;

    @Column(name = "active")
    @NotNull
    private boolean active;

    @Column(name = "is_deleted")
    @NotNull
    private boolean deleted;

    @Column(name = "date_of_creation")
    @Temporal(TemporalType.TIMESTAMP)
    @NotNull
    private Date dateOfCreation;

    @OneToMany(mappedBy = "employee")
    private List<ClientSuggestion> clientSuggestions;


    //Constructors
    //Getters ans setters
}
```

ClientSuggestion.java

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "er_suggestion")
public class ClientSuggestion implements Serializable {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    @Column(name = "id")
    private Long id;

    @Column(name = "content", unique = true)
    @NotNull
    @Size(max = 200)
    private String suggestion;

    @ManyToOne
    @JoinColumn(name = "employee_id")
    private Employee employee;

    //Constructors
    //Getters ans setters
}
```

EmployeeRepository.java

```
public interface EmployeeRepository extends CrudRepository<Employee, Long> {
```

ClientSuggestionRepository .java

```
public interface ClientSuggestionRepository extends CrudRepository<ClientSuggestion, Long> {
}
```

The event handler

```
@Component
@RepositoryEventHandler(ClientSuggestion.class)
public class ClientSuggestionEventHandler {
    Employee employee= (Employee ) SecurityContextHolder.getContext().getAuthentication().getPrincipal();

    @HandleBeforeCreate
    public void handleClientSuggestionBeforeCreate(ClientSuggestion cs) {
       cs.setDeleted(false);
       cs.setActive(true);
       cs.setPasswordResetToken(Encryptor.generateHash(cs.getPassword, 512));
       cs.setEmployee(employee);
    }
}
```

The bean, ClientSuggestionEventHandler, is registered in a configuration class. When I tried running the project, NullPointerException exception is thrown. I wish to find out how to get the current logged employee.
I'm new to Spring Security OAuth2. Thanks.

Comment: Did you init the `private List<ClientSuggestion> clientSuggestions;` in your codes?

Comment: Maybe you can try to put `SecurityContextHolder.getContext().getAuthentication().getPrincipal()` inside `handleClientSuggestionBeforeCreate`

Comment: @varren thanks. It worked. Merci beaucoup.

Answer (score 1):

In `Employee.java` implement `org.springframework.security.core.userdetails.UserDetails` class

**Employee.java**

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "er_employee")
public class Employee implements Serializable, UserDetails {
```

And then use `Employee employee= (Employee) SecurityContextHolder.getContext().getAuthentication().getPrincipal();`

Comment: Had already implemented UserDetails and UserDetails service. Security and Oauth2 worked. Just wanted to extract the currently logged in employee when an oncreate event is triggered (of type ClientSuggestion).  Code works fine. Just added-->  Employee employee = employeeRepository.findByUsername(SecurityContextHolder.getContext().getAuthentication().getName()); to @HandleBeforeCreate public void handleClientSuggestionBeforeCreate{...}